# How to change the content control placeholder text font style w.r.p to document font style

Tags: c#, word-contentcontrol

I am developing a word add-in using VS c#. As a requirement I need to add a content control to document on a ribbon button click. I am successful in adding content control with placeholder text. But the font style of the placeholder text is always set to default. I need to modify the font style according the font style set by the user on the current document.

How Can I change the font style of content control placeholder text ?

Comment: How does this have 2 upvotes already? Anyway, @Anup, you should really show us some code, or show what you have tried.

Comment: I used below lines of code to add Content Control to doc.
Word.ContentControls contentControls = null;
Word.ContentControl textContentControl = null;
 textContentControl = contentControls.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText, selectionRange);
textContentControl.SetPlaceholderText(null, null, "placeholder text");

By using above code I can insert a content control with placeholder "placeholder text". I need to change the font style of this placeholder text. How can I achieve this through code?